# Items doesn't appear in ListBox in C#, but in XAML yes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a little problem with a ListBox.
If I add an item by code, as it :

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(new MyData());
<ListBox Name="ListBox1" Height="Auto"
                    Style="{DynamicResource MyListBoxStyle}"/>
```

my ListBox display nothing, while Items contain the good number of item that I have add.

But if I put an item directy in my XAML and also in c#, MyData appear correctly :

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(new MyData());
<ListBox Name="ListBox1" Height="Auto"
                    Style="{DynamicResource MyListBoxStyle}">
                            <data:MyData/>
                        </ListBox>
```

Anyone know why it doesn't display correctly if I don't put an item in my XAML, and how to correct it?

Thank you in advance :)

---

**[SOLVED]**
My ListBox was already shown when I adding an item. So to solve this problem, just ask to update layout to notify that ItemSource has change :

```
ListBox1.UpdateLayout();
```

Comment: Better technique in wpf is data binding. you should bind an observable collection to List Box and add items to your observable collection. this causes the list box notify on changes in collection and refresh it's data that displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because the ListBox1.Items collection does not implement the INotifyPropertyChanged/INotifyCollectionChanged. You could create an observable collection an assign it to the ItemSource.

```
ObservableCollection<MyData> items = new ObservableCollection()

items.Add(new MyData());

ListBox1.ItemSource = items;
```

The reason you don't see it added, is that the listbox is already created/filled and the collection of Items does not notify the listbox when you call the .Add method on the Items property.

Comment: Good workaround. It is hard to tell from the question whether MyData is a collection already though. It implies it is, so you may need to revise this.

Comment: Even when MyData is a collection, it will be handled as one single item for the listbox. The point is, that using the ListBox1.Items.Add will not trigger the UI to update. ItemSource will.

Comment: After re-reading I am inclined to agree with your interpretation of the problem. I was trying to solve the code issue rather than the actual question asked "why does it work differently?". I have deleted my answer and comments to avoid detracting from the real issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help !

"The reason you don't see it added, is that the listbox is already created/filled and the collection of Items does not notify the listbox"

This sentence has made a "tilt" in my head.
By using "ListBox1.UpdateLayout();" it works, so I imaging that the problem was the notify :)

Thank you again for your help, problem solved !